# How can I convince Safari to be responsible for ttp:// URLs as well as http:// URLs?

Tags: safari, url, http

When somebody sends me a URL in an email, it is opened by Safari.

But often people make a mistake when copying the links (how I do not know) and the URL starts with ttp:// instead of http://.

Is there a way to teach Safari to feel responsible for ttp URLs as well and open them as http URLs?

Comment: From time to time, you stumble upon intentional h-omissions (or other constructs like hxxp), which have been done [for a reason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hxxp). All the more reason why browsers shouldn't treat ttp:// as http://, in addition to other answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell Safari to open ttp URLs by adding this to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` and restarting (logging out and back in isn't enough).

```
<dict>
    <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
    <string>com.apple.Safari</string>
    <key>LSHandlerURLScheme</key>
    <string>ttp</string>
</dict>
```

I don't know how to redirect them to http URLs though.

Comment: But does Safari afterwards now what to do with an URL starting with "ttp://apple.com/"?

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The "http://" part of a URL defines the protocol to use when connecting to the resource. "Http" is reserved for hypertext/web-type stuff. Two ther protocols include "ftp://" for file transfers and "afp://" is Apple file protocol.

Asking Safari to assume that "ttp://" should mean "http://" because someone who professes to know how to use a computer does not understand the significance of failing to select **one character** when copying and pasting is akin to demanding blind spot monitoring equipment on cars, just because self-professed drivers fail to set their side-view mirrors properly to see into their "blind spots".

Wait, near-economy cars now come with nanny equipment! I retract my comments.

Comment: (Sorry I badly edited yr comment yesterday.)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you can't, and you don't want to.

Every page on the web has an address, its URL. If the URL is not accurately input in the browser, the browser can't locate it or connect.

If you'd like to learn more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator

Updated browsers can usually handle input of just the host name.

So Safari can find "aol.com" -- but a broken URL, such as omitting the "h", is just meaningless text.

Knowing this, there are easy ways to handle your problem. A long, complex url, you might want to copy and paste into Stickies--add the "h" and it will turn into a clickable link.

And perhaps educate your friends as to what a web link, the URL, looks like. If they send you a link that's not broken, it's clickable from the email.